# Rails is not accepting arrays in AJAX calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My junk:

```
jQuery 1.3.2
Rails 2.3.5
```

If I perform a simple AJAX call like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
    dataType: "script",
    data: { value: ['1', '2'] }
});
```

Only `2` will return, not `1` and `2` .

Inside the HTTP POST headers in Firebug, it does say that is sending both :

```
authenticity_token  bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI=
authenticity_token  bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI=
value   1
value   2
Source
value=1&value=2&authenticity_token=bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI%3D&authenticity_token=bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI%3D
```

But when it hits my debugger in my `create` method :

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"bMmx0pnJ6ePq6ogwSCR1JH55U7wtrMEOy6ME4rNRmCI=",
 "action"=>"create",
 "value"=>"2",
 "controller"=>"admin/distributions",
 "email_id"=>"3"}
```

What might be going on here?

**UPDATE**

If I do this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/emails/" + id + "/distributions",
    dataType: "script",
    data: { value: ["1",[data.value]], type: data.type }
});
```

I can get all the zips to pass through..

Comment: you should show your controller code.

Comment: the debugger is right above `def create`, there's nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

You should use such data format for this request

```
data: { value[0]: '1', value[1]: '2'}
```

this code make correct hash

```
var c = ['1', '2'];
var i = 0;
var b = {}; //hash for data:
c.each(function(zz){
  b["value[" + i +"]"] = zz;
  i=i+1;
});
```

usage:

```
data: b
```